# Does being blacklisted by Spam Cannibal effects SEO

Tags: seo, email, spam

I have checked old post regarding being blocked by email spam agents and it states that SEO shouldn't be effected.

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/msag60JAWBc

I am wondering if the post above still relevant?

Answer (score 1):

You linked to a very old post and likely not correct.

### Keep reading, there is good news here!

Google, at least, will check black-lists and negatively down-grade a sites performance for appearing on some black-lists. Which black-lists are used is not entirely clear. What I do know is that the black-lists with longer expiration are ignored. For example, some black-lists will retain a record for as long as a year. The good new is this. These lists are almost always ignored except for some networks such as AT&T and only used for e-mail spam indication. Appearance on a black-list goes to a sites trust rank metrics.

### Now the good news!

Google understands that many innocent sites can end-up on a black-list and gives some level of grace. If you can clean-up the sites appearance on the black list, this can help. Short appearances on a black-list will not hurt. However, appearing on several black-lists for longer periods and repeatedly will.

Comment: The problem with my site is that we run it on the 1and1 managed server and unable to change PTR record (1and1 doesnt allow it on managed servers)... the generic PTR record that 1and1 is using is by default blocked by spam cannibal (http://www.spamcannibal.org/statsgeneric.html), which is ridiculous if to be honest... for all our emails we use different server.. it seems as if everyone has to have atleast VPS to avoid getting blacklisted.

Comment: @user3402600 sounds like you should take your business else where. 1and1 are dreadful, I administrate about 3 accounts on there on behalf of clients and by far one of the worst companies I work with daily. Try Rackspace, not only more knowledgeable but faster tier network too.

Comment: I have only used dedicated servers with 1and1, mostly, if there are any issues they would resolve them quickly after giving them a call, 10-20 minutes and issue has gone... the only issue that i have every had that took time was with Plesk panel, which took 2-3 hours and member of staff from plesk had to deal with. But back to the topic, shared hosting (most) have generic PTR and so do VPS, expect for lucky few.. Dedicated server starts at about £50+ it seems like a BS to me that for being on the black list for PTR you would have poorer ranking

Comment: @user3402600 Simon is right about 1&1. Their reputation is terrible. I keep track of hackers, scrapers, and spammers and 1&1 is a rather permissive company which allows bad actors to do whatever. This often effects other users negatively. This is probably what is happening to you. For some black-lists, just one bad IP in a block can effect the entire block for a year.